# Kneeling and Rock Throwing in Terra Formars

Tags: terra-formars

In the fight between Adolf Reinhart and the cockroaches, why did the cockroaches use their kneeling friends to step on as they threw the rocks? Does doing this increases the attack power? If yes, did humans do the same thing during the age where we fought one another using similar weapons?